# Using Facebook OAuth 2.0 - How do I fetch the access token?

Tags: javascript, facebook, oauth

I am new to [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), and I'm trying to use [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Connect) with my web-application.

I have succeded in getting a verification token, but my problem is "fetching" the access token. How do I fetch it? The Facebook documentation tells me to fetch the access token with this URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?'
                + 'client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX& redirect_uri=http://www.mysite.com/fbconn/index.html&display=touch&'
                + 'client_secret=axxxxxcxxxxxxxxxxx&code=' + code;
```

When I use this I see the access token on a blank page, but I want to fetch it with JavaScript (Ajax), PHP or something. Is this possible? I thought the access token would be appended to my redirect URI like the verfication code, but I never get redirected to my page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is PHP file_get_contents the way to go maybe?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `&type=user_agent` to the request. You will get the AuthToken with a hash marker in the following format.

```
http://yourredirecturi#code=[accesstoken]
```

If you set the request to `&type=web_server`, you'll get the AuthToken as a query string parameter: `http://yourredirecturi&code=[accesstoken]`.

Here is a full explanation of how to implement the Facebook's OAuth protocol. The code samples are in ASP.NET MVC, but it should translate well enough to any language:

***[Facebook Platform's OAuth 2.0 Protocol and ASP.NET MVC](http://amirrajan.net/Blog/asp-mvc-and-facebook-single-sign-on)***

Comment: I'm surprised the parameter `type` is not documented on the [official authentication help page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). I spent a few days, trying to figure out how to process access token received in a URI fragment on a server side, and if not your answer, I'd spent much more! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to try the following PHP snippet for getting your access token:

```
//Fill in the parts in caps with your app details
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE_YOU_GOT_FROM_THE_SERVER";

$token=file_get_contents($token_url); //Fetching the token from the URL

echo $token; //This is your access token
```

Thanks,

Answer (score -5):

```
$token = file_get_contents("the access token URL");
```

will give you the access token.

Comment: -1 What is the access token url? Horrible answer, very vague.