# How to fetch all facebook data which needs access token?

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I am trying to fetch user data from facebook using facebook PHP SDK. (I am developing the site in codeigniter). I am able to fetch all the basic data. But I am not able to fetch those data which need access token. I am taking the access token parameter from the logout url by parsing the url. But that token is not working. Is it different from the main access token?

This is my controller file

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserRegistration2 extends CI_Controller { 
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->model('test/Facebook_model');
}

function index() {

    $fb_data = $this->Facebook_model->get_data();

    if((!$fb_data['uid']) or (!$fb_data['me'])) {

        echo "<a href='" .$fb_data['loginUrl']. "'>Login</a>";
    }
    else {
        $params = null;
        parse_str($fb_data['logoutUrl'], $params);
        $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/music?access_token=" . $params['access_token'];
        //$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

        echo "<pre>";

        print_r($fb_data);

        //print_r($user);
        //print_r($params);
        echo "</pre>";
        echo "<a href='" .$graph_url. "'>Get Music</a>";
        echo "<a href='" .$fb_data['logoutUrl']. "'>Logout</a>";

    }
}
}
```

This is my model file

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $config = array(
                    'appId'  => '130090207121542',
                    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    'fileUpload' => true
                    );

    $this->load->library('facebook/Facebook', $config);

}

function get_data() { 
    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
    $profile = null;
    if($user)
    {
        try {
            $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
    }

    $fb_data = array(
                    'me' => $profile,
                    'uid' => $user,
                    'loginUrl' => $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(
                        array(
                            'scope' => 'email,user_interests,user_birthday,publish_stream',
                            'redirect_uri' => 'http://herle.in/flutter/index.php/test/userRegistration2.html'
                        )
                    ),
                    'logoutUrl' => $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(),
                );

    return $fb_data;
}
}
```

**EDIT:**

Found a link to this question
[Using Facebook OAuth 2.0 - How do I fetch the access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988236/using-facebook-oauth-2-0-how-do-i-fetch-the-access-token)

But don't know whther it's going to work or not. Because I don't have any idea of getting the CODE (THE_CODE_YOU_GOT_FROM_THE_SERVER) to pass it into the url. If it's going to work then how can I get this CODE?

**UPDATE 18/04/12**

It's working now. In scope I was not taking permission for "user_likes" from the user.

Comment: Where are your calls to get your page, user and application access tokens?

Comment: That's what I'm asking. How can I get the access token to pass it into the "graph_url" variable? If it's the wrong way then please suggest me a alternate solution.

Comment: 1. for future reference please never expose your app secret publicly, it is dangerous and against Facebook TOS

Comment: 2. Let me repost your code in a new answer with tokens added.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to erase it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made changes. and it's working now

This is my controller file

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserRegistration2 extends CI_Controller { 
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->model('test/Facebook_model');
}

function index() {

    $fb_data = $this->Facebook_model->get_data();

    if((!$fb_data['uid']) or (!$fb_data['me'])) {

        echo "<a href='" .$fb_data['loginUrl']. "'>Login</a>";
    }
    else {
        $params = null;
        parse_str($fb_data['logoutUrl'], $params);
        $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/music?access_token=" . $params['access_token'];
        //$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

        echo "<pre>";

        print_r($fb_data);

        //print_r($user);
        //print_r($params);
        echo "</pre>";
        echo "<a href='" .$graph_url. "'>Get Music</a>";
        echo "<a href='" .$fb_data['logoutUrl']. "'>Logout</a>";

    }
}
}
```

This is my model file

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $config = array(
                    'appId'  => '130090207121542',
                    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    'fileUpload' => true
                    );

    $this->load->library('facebook/Facebook', $config);

}

function get_data() { 
    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
    $profile = null;
    if($user)
    {
        try {
            $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
    }

    $fb_data = array(
                    'me' => $profile,
                    'uid' => $user,
                    'loginUrl' => $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(
                        array(
                            'scope' => 'email,user_interests,user_birthday,publish_stream,user_likes',
                            'redirect_uri' => 'http://herle.in/flutter/index.php/test/userRegistration2.html'
                        )
                    ),
                    'logoutUrl' => $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(),
                );

    return $fb_data;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i Request the user, and application access_tokens. 
 I will edit in any other answers needed here.

---

```
$access_token = $_SESSION['fb_135669679827333_access_token']; 
// replace app id, gets user token
```

---

```
// gets app access token in the form of access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
$app_access_token = GetCH();
function GetCH(){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=135669679827333&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS,20000);
if(substr($url,0,8)=='https://'){
    // The following ensures SSL always works. A little detail:
    // SSL does two things at once:
    //  1. it encrypts communication
    //  2. it ensures the target party is who it claims to be.
    // In short, if the following code is allowed, CURL won't check if the 
    // certificate is known and valid, however, it still encrypts communication.
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
}
$sendCH = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $sendCH;
};
```

---

FURTHER MORE: To retrieve the user token you must first have at least basic permissions from the user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I'm putting the this url https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=135669679827333&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials in the browser, it's displaying "access_token=130090207121542|xm3P_L6SrAMVY3-DZRGbl9E_o6k". Is this the token I can pass it to the "graph url" variable? Actually I want to fetch the data like this url https://graph.facebook.com/me/music?access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAMpsZCUIFqBAMYzAgKcX2mVMfZCxfIZAjlr53jOju3yThDfozeJ5wZCdtNmcZCCtIbEEn6XXhmg9GQmZAdm5d2Fx0 and then I'll decode it and place it in my database.

Comment: be sure to mark the answer correct if it is working so other users may find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $config = array(
                        'appId'  => '130090207121542',
                        'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                        'fileUpload' => true
                        );

        $this->load->library('facebook/Facebook', $config);

    }
   $access_token = $_SESSION['fb_130090207121542_access_token'];
    function get_data() { 
        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();
        $profile = null;
        if($user)
        {
            try {
                $profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');

    // replace app id, gets user token 
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                $user = null;
            }
        }

        $fb_data = array(
                        'me' => $profile,
                        'uid' => $user,
                        'loginUrl' => $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(
                            array(
                                'scope' => 'email,user_interests,user_birthday,publish_stream',
                                'redirect_uri' => 'http://herle.in/flutter/index.php/test/userRegistration2.html'
                            )
                        ),
                        'logoutUrl' => $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(),
                    );

        return $fb_data;
    }

    //
    // gets app access token in the form of access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    $app_access_token = GetCH();
    function GetCH(){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=135669679827333&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&grant_type=client_credentials");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS,20000);
    if(substr($url,0,8)=='https://'){
        // The following ensures SSL always works. A little detail:
        // SSL does two things at once:
        //  1. it encrypts communication
        //  2. it ensures the target party is who it claims to be.
        // In short, if the following code is allowed, CURL won't check if the 
        // certificate is known and valid, however, it still encrypts communication.
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH,CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    }
    $sendCH = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $sendCH;
    };
```

---

```
class UserRegistration2 extends CI_Controller { 
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->model('test/Facebook_model');
}

function index() {

    $fb_data = $this->Facebook_model->get_data();

    if((!$fb_data['uid']) or (!$fb_data['me'])) {

        echo "<a href='" .$fb_data['loginUrl']. "'>Login</a>";
    }
    else {
        $params = null;
        parse_str($fb_data['logoutUrl'], $params);
        $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/music?access_token=" . $access_token;
        //$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));

        echo "<pre>";

        print_r($fb_data);

        //print_r($user);
        //print_r($params);
        echo "</pre>";
        echo "<a href='" .$graph_url. "'>Get Music</a>";
        echo "<a href='" .$fb_data['logoutUrl']. "?access_token=" .$access_token. "'>Logout</a>";

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I was not aware that we can get access token this way also ($access_token = $_SESSION['fb_130090207121542_access_token']; ). I'll check it.

Comment: It's not working. The variable returns the same token as that of the one I was extracting from the logout url. Whenever I place it in the "graph_url" variable, it doesn't any data.